# How can I get updated parameter from CallFunc? (cocos2d-x V3.0)

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to get updated the parameter time from `CallFunc`. However, the time I got from `CallFunc` where I updated, is always ZERO. That is `DelayTime::create(updatedTime)` is ZERO.

Do anyone know how to use parameter from `CallFunc` in `DelayTime`?

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Please provide your code. We don't understand your question.

2/ Both `CallFunc` and `DelayTime` return an cocos2d::Action, you can't call one of them inside each other.

3/ **`CallFunc:`**
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/d3/d32/classcocos2d_1_1_call_func.html
function define: `static CallFunc* create (Ref *target, SEL_CallFunc selector)`
example:

`using namespace cocos2d;
class A() : Node` //(or anything that inherited Ref)
`{/*...(defined function f())...*/}`

```
A *a = new A();
CallFunc* callFunc = CallFunc::create(a, SEL_CallFunc(&A::f));
a->runAction(callFunc);
```

**`DelayTime:`**
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/d5/d58/classcocos2d_1_1_delay_time.html
function define: `static DelayTime* create(float d)`
example:

```
A *a = new A();
DelayTime* wait = DelayTime::create(4);
a->runAction(wait); // this is useless, you must put a DelayTime in a Sequence
```

p/s: Sequence is an Action, too. To create a Sequence, use
`Sequence* seq = Sequence::create(action1, action2, action3, NULL);`